# Efficient bit manipulation in Java?

Tags: java, c++, bit-manipulation, time-complexity, bit

I am a Java programmer, and I have recently started competitive coding (Codechef, Hackerearth, etc..)

I have a feeling that bit manipulation is really very slow in Java when it comes to **very large input values**. From my experience, the same C/C++ code (*By same i mean if converted from java with same algorithm, same strategy, etc. I am not changing my logic when converting from Java to C/C++ or vice à versa*) which runs all test cases successfully, generates a *time limit exceeded* in Java. I am aware that most competitive programming sites provide 2x execution time for Java programs, but still it crosses the time limit.

In languages like C++, we have functions like `__builtin_popcount` which can exploit CPU inbuilt functions that are very fast. Such things are not available in Java. Some functions like `java.lang.Integer.bitCount()` will only work for a 32-bit `int`.

So should we prefer going with C++ for such problems? Should we even consider solving bit manipulation type problems using Java? If not, then are there any super fast **efficient** tricks rather than applying our own logic?

(There is also the fact that different architecture machines will take different amount of time, but lets ignore that. My question is in the context of competitive programming)

Comment: Why is this tagged C++? Language recommendations really aren't fact based, we can't provide an answer that isn't just based in opinion.

Comment: Bit manipulation is not slow in Java, and Java has bitwise operators similar to C/C++. You are probably doing other things that make it slow, such as boxing/unboxing. Without seeing your Java code we can't tell what makes it slow.

Comment: There's no `__builtin_popcount` in C++. If your program times out, it's because your solution is inefficient, not because of Java. If you need to resort to compiler intrinsics in order to not time out in C++, you're doing something wrong.

Comment: There's no `__builtin_popcount` in C either.

Comment: @Jesper  I have not mentioned any particular problem/program because my question is generic. The same C/C++ code if converted to Java, with same strategy and algorithm, etc..  Still, for a reference, consider a program of counting how many numbers between a given range have two set bits.

Comment: @molbdnilo I have not mentioned any particular problem/program because my question is generic. The same C/C++ code if converted to Java, with same strategy and algorithm, etc..  Still, for a reference, consider a program of counting how many numbers between a given range have two set bits.

Comment: @VijayChavda That sounds like a combinatorics problem that is supposed to be too slow to brute-force. (Brute-forcing "how many 64-bit numbers with two set bits are there?" will literally take hundreds of years, but is done in no time if you employ The Ancient Power Of Maths.)

Comment: Consider that even if you want to brute force it, there is a simple way to go from a number with k bits set to the next higher number with k bits set, you don't have to visit the stuff in between.

Comment: This is why i didn't mention any particular scenario in the first case - i would really like to know the answer in a general case scenario. I know a given problem can be optimized in many different ways. But here my point is to know if for same type of situation java would be efficient or not? :)

Answer (score 4):

`Long` has bitCount too, and lowestOneBit, numberOfLeadingZeroes, numberOfTrailingZeroes etcetera.

And then there is `BitSet`, more for boolean purposes.

Those operations are in small short running programs horribly slow as the Just-In-Time compiler does not kick in.

Java is not C, but reverting inside a java program to C/C++ for those kind of operations, often do not merit because of the JNI overhead.

Till now I found java sufficient for reaching similar performance, even where one would not expect it. It is in allocations where java can beat C/C++ at times. But nobody beats C on the calculatory level, how for instance `n % 12` is calculated.

Comment: Yes, I agree. These methods are slow, and some of them are designed only for a fixed bit length. I think perhaps this is the reason that for really large values it'll be slow.